# Integration of $\frac{1}{x}$ without implying

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I  would like to compute the $I = \int\frac{1}{x}dx$ without directly implying it to be $\ln(x)$. I do know that $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. This can simply be proven as :

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{let } y =& \ln(x) \quad\Rightarrow \quad
e^y = x \\
\text{differentiate both sides  }\quad e^y dy =&dx \quad\quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{e^y}=\frac{1}{x}
\end{aligned}
$$

We can also prove that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$ using Taylor's Series.
Now how can we show that $\int\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln x $ assuming $x>0$

Comment: In my universe, $\ln(x)$ is, by definition, $\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t}\, \mathrm{d}t.$$  How have *you* defined the natural logarithm?

Comment: Well, you do know that $\ln w$ is *defined* to be $\int_1^w \frac 1x dx$ and that $e^x$ is defined as $\ln^{-1}(x)$, don't you?

Comment: Else, you need to show that $\int \frac 1x dx= \ln |x| + C$.

Comment: If $\frac {d\ln x}{dx} = \frac 1x$ then by the Fundamental Theorem of calculus $\int \frac 1x dx = \ln x + C$.

Comment: I think for many people the natural log function is defined to be the inverse of the exponential function. Not everyone uses this approach that some real analysis books take of defining $\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson i have always defined $ln(x)$ to be the inverse of $e^x$ while definig $e^x = \lim{b \to \infty}(1+x/n)^n$

Comment: @Onyambu Great!  That definition should be a part of your question.  I usually define the exponential as the unique differentiable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(x)f(y) = f(x+y)$ with $f(0)=f'(0)=1$.  It is fun exercise to show that the exponential, defined this way, is the inverse of the logarithm, as I defined it in my first comment.  The underlying point here is that all of these objects can be defined in different (though ultimately equivalent) ways, and the precise definitions you have in mind dictate how you answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can perform a substitution $$\ x={e}^{u}, dx={e}^{u}du$$
So the final integral will be $$\ \int du=u+c$$ Now undo the substitution, and get the integral as $$\ \ln x+c$$
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also do you think you can help  with solving $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^x}{x}dx$ I googled and found a relation to something called Exponential Integrals. But no definite answers

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is define a function $L: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ by $L(x) = \int_1^x 1/t \ dt$ and then prove, using the Riemann integral for instance, that $L(a) = L(ab) - L(b)$ (you dilate the area horizontally the inverse of the amount that you dilate it vertically), which gives you $L(ab) = L(a) + L(b)$. You also need to prove continuity, but with these two properties, you are necessarily dealing with *a* logarithm.

Proving that its the natural logarithm is really about what you're assuming is true and what you're proving. It would perhaps be interesting to see a first principle proof that $L( (1+1/n)^n )$ converges to $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity, but it could also be entirely tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a^u$ so $\,dx=a^u\ln a\,du$ with $a\in\mathbb{R^+}-\{1\}$ $$\begin{align}\int\frac{\,dx}{x}&=\int\frac{a^u\ln a}{a^u}\,du\\&=\ln a\int \,du\\&=u\ln a+C\\&=\log_ax\log_e a +C\\&=\log_e a^{log_a x}+C\\&=\log_e x+C\\&=\ln x +C \end{align}$$